# Не отправляются письма через форму

Tags: php

**1) Имеется форма в index.php:**

```
<label style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 500;">ФОРМА</label>
<form class="Modal_content effect1" class="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="feedback-form">
<input type="text" name="nameFF" id="nameFF" required placeholder="ФИО" x-autocompletetype="name" class="">
<br>
<input type="text" name="phoneFF" id="phoneFF" required placeholder="Номер телефона" x-autocompletetype="phone" class="">
<br>
<input type="email" name="contactFF" id="contactFF" required placeholder="e-mail адрес" x-autocompletetype="email" class="">
<br>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px;"><div class="content">
<input type="file" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute;" name="fileFF[]" multiple id="fileFF" class="inputfile inputfile-3" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected">
<label for="fileFF"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"></path></svg> <span>Прикрепить файлы</span></label>
</div></div><br>
<textarea name="messageFF" id="messageFF" rows="5" placeholder="Детали заявки…" class=""></textarea>
<br>
<input style="padding-top: 6px; color:#777777;" value="Отправить" type="submit" id="submitFF">
</form>
```

**2) файл mail2.js**

```
    document.getElementById('feedback-form').addEventListener('submit', function(evt){
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest(), f = this;
  evt.preventDefault();
  http.open("POST", "contacts.php", true);
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
      if (http.responseText.indexOf(f.nameFF.value) == 0) { 
        f.messageFF.removeAttribute('value');
        f.messageFF.value='';
      }
    }
  }
  http.onerror = function() {
    alert('Извините, данные не были переданы');
  }
  http.send(new FormData(f));
}, false);
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form1 input1').change(function () {
    $('form1 p1').text(this.files.length + " file(s) selected");
  });
});
```

**3) файл contacts.php**

```
    if (isset ($_POST['contactFF'])) {
  $to = "мой ящик";
  $from = $_POST['contactFF'];
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "ФИО: ".$_POST['nameFF']."\n"."Номер: ".$_POST['phoneFF']."\nEmail: ".$from."\n".$_SERVER['']."\n".$_POST['messageFF'];
  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message";
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['fileFF']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['fileFF']['tmp_name'][$i])));
         $filename = $_FILES['fileFF']['name'][$i];
         $filetype = $_FILES['fileFF']['type'][$i];
         $filesize += $_FILES['fileFF']['size'][$i];
         $message.="

--$boundary
Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

$attachment";
     }
   }
   $message.="
--$boundary--";

  if ($filesize < 10000000) {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $_POST['nameFF'].', Ваше сообщение получено, спасибо!';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 10 МБ.';
  }
}
```

Все три файла находятся в одной директории 
В index.php подключен mail2.js `<script src="mail2.js"></script>`
В mail2.js указан contacts.php (и c полным путем пробовал http://...) 
Вместо **"мой ящик"** свою почту.

**Но данные с формы так и не приходят на ящик**

Пожалуйста помогите разобраться в чем ошибка.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь библиотекой swiftmailer/swiftmailer. Ваш код больно читать. Вы бы ради разнообразия проверяли, что возвращают функции. Без лога ошибок только вы можете себе помочь

Comment: "Ваш код больно читать"))))))) сам в шоке)) Спасибо буду разбираться, а логи хз где их достать

Answer (score 1):

А почему в файле mail2.js добрая половина сделана на ванильке??)) это на джиквери делается ОДНОЙ строчкой!!! ведь джиквери у вас таки подключен...

**По вопросу** - вы бы указали "мой ящик" - какой именно? наверное майл-ру или гугл?)) там ваш метод mail.php давно и надолго забанен!
Используйте отправку через smtp, на GIT есть неплохая либа. https://github.com/Ipatov/SendMailSmtpClass

Comment: Моя ошибка что отстал от жизни. Спасибо за инфу!! как приду к чему либо напишу